# Are cars really allowed to join the race in the middle?

Tags: realism, cars-3

In the climax scenes of *[Cars 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cars_3)* , there is a wreck on the race car track.  There's a dialogue between two cars.

> Well, the green light is on and the pit road is open. Everybody is coming in.

At that point of time, many cars which are not the contestants of the piston cup also join the race.

Is this a failure of the security in the movie or people are allowed to join in real life races too? When there are cases of wreckage on the track, are new racers allowed to join the race in real life races like street racing, formula races? Are cars shown in the film equivalent to the crowd in real life? (Like some crowd may get there when there's an accident).

Answer (score 4):

No, real life auto racing does not allow for substitutions unless it's a driver substitution for a car that's already running in the race.

A car may be substituted, but only if the team [crashed their car during qualifying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASCAR_rules_and_regulations#Car_and_driver_changes).  Also, that car will then have to start at the back of the pack no matter what position they qualified.

New racing teams which did not qualify and start the race are not allowed to enter the race under any conditions.